# Is it possible if i get 2 outputs from 1 xml task on SSIS?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, ssis

I have an XML TASK with input operation type is XSLT  on my SSIS. So I want to get 2 outputs there, I want `.csv` and `.txt` to be my output.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually rather trivial. Inside of your data flow task, you will want to connect the xml source to a Multicast transform.

You can then connect as many outputs as you need from the Multicast, so you can connect it to two Raw File Destinations

[image: SSIS Data Flow Task]